# Same secret for multiple deployments in Helm chart

Tags: jwt, kubernetes-helm, helm3, kubernetes-secrets, supabase

I am using [supabase-community/supabase-kubernetes](https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-kubernetes) to deploy Supabase in Kubernetes.

For Studio, Storage, Kong, Realtime, Rest and Auth services, you need to define at least jwt secret or in some cases the [anon or service key](https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-kubernetes/blob/2f95f43a3073c9d323dee4c3dac158187e344861/charts/supabase/values.example.yaml#L9).

However, I have two problems with this kind of configuration:

1. You need to configure the same secret information multiple times in `values.yaml`
2. The secrets won't be stored in a K8s `secret`

To improve these two aspects, I propose two configure those values in a dedicated section, e.g.:

```yaml
  jwtSecrets:
    anonKey: "JWT_ANON_KEY"
    serviceKey: "JWT_SERVICE_KEY"
    key: "YOUR_SUPER_SECRET_JWT_TOKEN_WITH_AT_LEAST_32_CHARACTERS_LONG"
```

When rendered with the templates, a "global" secret gets created and every service (Studio, Storage, Kong, etc.) references this secret in its configuration:

```yaml
          env:
          ...
            - name: SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: my-jwt-secret
                  key: anonKey
```

However, I am unsure if this is best practice for Helm charts?, to have such global configuration sections? Besides, I would like to know where to define this *global secret creation* — in `_helpers.tpl`?

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Declaring a Secret in your chart and referencing it from your chart's Deployments is totally fine; there's no rule that each Deployment must have its own Secret.  Some third-party charts have the ability to inject external Secrets into them (but not all).  I don't know that there's a specific "best practice" here, beyond that there are legitimate security concerns around passing actual secrets through Helm.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for your answer. I also thought of referencing the secret with `secretKeyRef`, whereas the secret needs to be created manually first. But this is cumbersome... When you speak of legitimate security concerns, what are you referring? As I know, the secrets would be in clear text in values.yaml.

Comment: Exactly: the secret values need to be passed along in plain text in several places and there are a couple of places they can be extracted (`helm get values`, `helm get manifest`, `kubectl get secret`, in the CI/CD system).

Comment: Yeah, I think in this case I will reference the secret with `secretKeyRef`, as I already do with my database connection credentials. That way, the user needs to create the secrets first and then reference it in their `values.yaml`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated out by @David Maze there is no best practice regarding one secret for multiple deployments in `values.yaml` of a Helm chart.

On grounds of convenience, the secret name should be referenced in `values.yaml` like this:

```yaml
jwtSecretName: my-secret
```

While the secret must be created by the user beforehand:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  jwtSecret: YWRtaW4=
  serviceKey: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
  anonKey: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
kind: Secret
```

This allows to store the secret data according to Kubernetes best practice and simplifies the configuration of Helm charts.